# How to use Clarke and Wright saving algorithm to afford heterogeneous fleet?

Tags: algorithms, program-optimization, routing

I want to solve Heterogeneous fleet in vehicle routing  problem using the Clarke and Wright saving algorithm. After reading many literature I found two options:

1. Explicit and early assignment for the route.
2. Using saving algorithm sequentially, and iterating over all generated routes to fulfill capacity constraints.

But I'm unsure about these two options. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial explaining how to use Clark and Wright heuristic for route optimization with savings matrix. https://www.biitlog.com/clarke-and-wright-heuristic/